# General timeout for GitHub Actions jobs

Tags: github-actions

I know that it is possible to set a timeout for individual jobs using the proprety `timeout-minutes`.

For example:

```
name: Spawn cluster

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  schedule:
    - cron:  '0 */12 * * *'
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 600
    steps:
    - name: CHECKOUT
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: AZURE LOGIN
      uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS}}
```

However in my case, with thousand of jobs definitions, this approach is really hard to implement.

Is there some way to configure a general timeout threshold for all my jobs in my self-hosted agent?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible at the moment. You can only set the timeout [individually at job](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idtimeout-minutes) and [step level](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepstimeout-minutes). However, the timeout can't be set for a complete workflow or several workflows. However, there is already [an open discussion](https://github.com/orgs/github-community/discussions/10690) about this on GitHub.